# gcloud compute ssh connects shows wrong instance name

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform

I'm pretty new to the Gcloud environment, but getting the hang of it.
Though with our first project live on an instance, I've been shuffeling some static IP's, instances and snapshots around for optimal deployment workflow. Though whats going on now, I can't understand;

I have two instances (i.e.) **live-1** and **dev-2**.
Now I can connect to live-1 using `gcloud compute ssh live-1` and it's okay.
When I try to connect to dev-2 using `gcloud compute ssh dev-2`, it logs me in to live-1.

The first time I tried to ssh to dev-2 it took longer than usual. After that it just connects me to the wrong instance immediately.

The goal was (as you might've guessed) to copy the live environment to a testing one. I did create an image of live-1, and cloned it to setup dev-2 with it. But in my earlier experience trying this, this was possible and worked as expected.

Whenever I use the Compute Console in the browser and use the online SSH tool from the instance list, it does connect to dev-2 properly. But on my local machine, using aformentioned command, connects me to live-1.

I already removed the IP for dev-2 from my known hosts, figuring it's cached somewhere, but no luck. What am I missing here?

**Edit:** I found out just now that the instances are separated though 'named' the same; if I login to dev-2, I do see `myuser@live-1:` in the shell, but it appears it is running a separate instance. I created a dummy file on the supposed `dev-2`, and it doesn't show up at the actual `live-1` machine.
So this is very confusing; I rely on the 'user-tag' thing in front of every shell line to know where and what I'm actually working on; having two instances with the same name but different environments is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was dead simple. Just run `sudo hostname [desiredhostname]` in the terminal, and restart it.

So in my case I logged in to `dev-2` and ran `sudo hostname dev-2`.